# I am not able to install any new gem in my rails application.Its a issue related to bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, simplecov

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)

    solargraph was resolved to 0.38.0, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.17.2)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.16.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 1.17.2)', which is required by gem 'rails (~> 5.2)', in any of the sources.
ERROR: 6
```

I am using ruby version 2.5.1 on my device and rvm is not installed earlier the version of ruby 3.0.2 but our project is of version 2.5.1. But while installing any new gem and hitting bundle install it shows this particular error

sudo docker-compose run --rm --no-deps web bundle install

Comment: Your `bundler` version seems to be too old. Try running `gem install bundler` to update bundler before running the failing command again.

Comment: No its of current version the ruby which i had on my device was of 3.0.2 but out project is written in ruby version 2.5.1 so i installed it but when I add any new gem its showing the above error. Also i tried the above command